# Problem with space separated user input in PHP console

Tags: php

In C, this code can take 2 space separated input. And then does it's job add or multiple.

```
int main()
{
    char inp[2];
    int num= 5, x;

    scanf("%s", inp);

    if (inp[0] == 'a')
    {
        scanf("%d", &x);
        num= num + x;
    }

    else if (inp[0] == 'm')
    {
        scanf("%d", &x);
        num= num * x;
    }

    printf("Result: %d", num);
}
```

for example-

a 5

Result: 10

But if I want the same task in PHP console it doesn't work. I tried like this-

```
<?php
$num= 5;

fscanf(STDIN, "%s ", $inp);

if ($inp == 'a')
{
    fscanf(STDIN, "%d", $x);
    $num= $num + $x;
}

elseif ($inp == 'm')
{
    fscanf(STDIN, "%d", $x);
    $num= $num * $x;
}

echo "Result: " . $num;
```

By pressing enter it can be do easily. But I need to do this by space separated input.

Any solution?

Comment: So what _does_ the PHP code do instead, with the same input?

Comment: After giving 2 input like 'a 5' if I press enter, it asks for another input. It doesn't separate 2 input by space.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. It works just like the C code.

```
<?php

$num= 5;
$x= null;

fscanf(STDIN, "%s %d", $inp, $x);

if ($inp == 'a')
{
    $num= $num + $x;
}

elseif ($inp == 'm')
{
    $num= $num * $x;
}

echo "Result: " . $num;
```